# terms in object oriented database

Tags: oracle, oop

i am studying   object orienting concepts in oracle and have some confusion  in some terms
for example,i know  how to create object type,but dont know what does mean not instantiable?

```
create or replace type compar_item_t as object(
com varchar2(50),
chint varchar2(254),

 not instantiable member function getChint
                  return varchar2,
                 member function print
                  return varchar2
) not instantiable not final;
```

does not instantiable  means that we can't instantiable it?or what does last term means?i meant  not instantiable not final; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this document might be helpful, if you're not already familiar with it:

> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/objects.htm
>
> Oracle object technology is a layer of abstraction built on Oracle's
>   relational technology.

Which implies "it's our product, so we're making up our own terminology as we go along" ;)

Anyway, what does Oracle mean by "instantiable" (a word I'm not sure you'll find in most dictionaries, and will probably be rejected by most spell-checkers ;))?  From the same link:

> Declaring a method as NOT INSTANTIABLE means that the type is not
>   providing an implementation for that method....
>
> A subtype of a NOT INSTANTIABLE type can override any of the
>   non-instantiable methods of the supertype and provide concrete
>   implementations. If there are any non-instantiable methods remaining,
>   the subtype must also necessarily be declared NOT INSTANTIABLE....

So I guess "non-instantiable" is similar to an "abstract base type" or an "interface" in most other OOP languages.

IMHO...

Comment: so it means,that object where,not instantiable is declare,can't access function?